# How to get number of fields with validation error on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I would like to show validation error message like " You've got 3 fields with errors" (then all the fields which contain error got highlighted) 
instead of showing rails default validation error message " 5 errors prohibited this listing from being saved"

i know we can get total numbers of validation errors using `obj.errors.count`
but how to get the total numbers of **fields** that have error, not the total number of validation errors?

Comment: Are you also considering nested attributes errors?

Comment: `obj.errors.keys` will give you the columns which have errors, you can do `obj.errors.keys.count` will give you the total number of fields having errors.

Comment: not at the moment, no nested attributes. this is just a simple database application for internal use. but it's interesting to know also the solution for nested attributes :)

Comment: @imran obj.errors.keys.count do the tricks! thank's. Since you brought it up, is it the same solution also applicable if i have nested attributes errors?

Comment: Yes, it will work for nested attributes as well because nested attributes column comes as `nested_model.nested_model_column_name`.
Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.errors.keys` will give you the columns which have errors, you can do `obj.errors.keys.count` to get the total number of fields having errors.

Also, it will work for nested attributes because the nested attributes column having error will come as `nested_model.nested_model_column_name`

Comment: Works!  also glad to know that it will also work for the nested attributes. Thank u very much